# WireMock query parameter: Use regex to match within a value which contains equality ("=") sign

Tags: c#, wiremock

I am using wiremock to mock my requests. However, I am not able to mock the URLs for which query values have equality sign. For ex:
`/my/relative/path?param1=updated>-10d AND projectId=10001`

As you can see the param1 value i.e `updated>-10d AND projectId=10001` contains `=` sign within the value. And I have to mock the responses based on the projectId. So if I do something like this:

```cs
MockServer
.Given('/my/relative/path')
.WithParam("param1", new RegexMatcher("*10001*"))
.RespondWith(Response
    .Create()
    .WithStatusCode(200)
    .WithHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    .WithBody("some body value"));
```

it doesn't work in this case. I have tried multiple combinations and I have observed that if the query value doesn't have `=` sign, then it works perfectly. But, how do I match it with my constraints i.e with the query value having `=` sign? Am I missing something really basic here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the actual URL something more like `/my/relative/path?param1=123&param2=321`?

Comment: No. The actual url accepts a query param which has a SQL like syntax (not exactly but yeah something of that sort) `/my/relative/path?sql=condition1 AND condition 2 OR condition3`. Here any of the condition could be of the form of something like `id >= 2` or `id = 2` etc..

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Wiremock version which I am using (1.0.17) has a bug which doesn't work correctly when the query has `=` sign as per this reported bug: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues/283

It got fixed in the version 1.0.19. So, I will switch to that version.